# Does the STD allocator dynamically allocate memory on the heap? does it safely delete memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

So I am trying to learn about the `std::allocator<>` in C++ and was confused from the reference sites about a few things. Especially since i read the construct and deconstruct methods of allocator are deprecated in C++17

This is the following code i wrote as an example

```
// Example with pointers and allocators
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>




int main()
{
  std::allocator<int> nums;
  int * first = nums.allocate(1); //is this on the heap, like with calling new int(4)?
  int * second = nums.allocate(2);
  *first = 7;
  second[0] = 2;
  second[1] = 4;
  std::cout << *first << std::endl;
  std::cout << second[1] << std::endl;
  nums.deallocate(first, 1); //is the int safely deleted from memory?
  nums.deallocate(second, 2);
}
```

When one calls the allocate method, does the pointer that's returned point to dynamic piece of memory on the heap or is that memory stack allocated?

Additionally, when one calls the deallocate method, is the pointer being deallocated also have it's object deleted from memory? is deallocate equivalent to `delete`?

Comment: If you read e.g. [this `allocate` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) you will see that it uses `::operator new`, which according [to this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) allocates from the *free store* which is the standardese name for the heap.

Comment: thx, but does it also delete the memory and the object it points to when deallocate is called?

Comment: Now that you've been given a link to the reference page for the allocator, how about trying to read it, and figuring it out yourself, and then asking a follow-up question if you don't understand something? Learning how to read and understand technical documentation is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: I have read the documentation  linked and I am aware both new and delete are called with allocate and deallocate. what confused me is `Calls ::operator delete(void*), but it is unspecified when and how it is called.`

Comment: There's a note at the bottom of the page you were directed to by the first comment, which addresses precisely this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When one calls the allocate method, does the pointer that's returned point to dynamic piece of memory on the heap

The C++ standard doesn't use the word *heap*, but yes `std::allocator` allocates from the *free store*, which is often called the heap because that is the data structure that is typically used to implement it.

> when one calls the deallocate method, is the pointer being deallocated also have it's object deleted from memory? is deallocate equivalent to `delete`?

`delete` does two things: It calls the destructor of the object and deallocates the memory. `std::allocator::deallocate` performs the latter part and only the latter. `std::allocator::destroy` performs the former. Note that it is not specified *when* the memory is deallocated, only that it is.